# Text of the anchor tag passed to the controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to get the text of the anchor tag passed to the controller?

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SearchStudent","Home")">Student Information</a>
```

This is in the view.

When I click the link, I want to use "Student Information" (the inner text) in the controller.

How can I get it programmatically? (No Hard coding)

I am using C#.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When do you want the text passed to the controller?

Comment: Do you put any dynamic value in the <a> tag?

Comment: @Vengadesh - No Its static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as `routeValues`.

In your view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SearchStudent","Home", new { innerText = "Student Information" })">Student Information</a>
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchStudent(string innerText)
{
   // Do your thing.
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Awesomely Great.! Thanks much. I tried it already but missed something before.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example if you really want to send inner text to controller

give id to your   tag like this

```
<a id="linkData">Student Information</a>
```

in jQuery add this

```
$('#linkData').click(function () {
            var dataLink = $('#linkData').text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", data: { data: dataLink }, url: "@Url.Action("SearchStudent","Home")", success: function (result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

In your controller add an argument like this

```
    public ActionResult SearchStudent(string data)
    {
        return  Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It will return data to function(result) and alert(result) to show your inner text.
Hope you understand me. I'm not good in English.